# Atualizar DIV sem refresh com Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tenho um ajax que manda através de `post`, algumas informações no PHP para uma outra página. Eu salvo essas informações na `session`.

Gostaria de atualizar a `div` onde tenho uma modal. No caso, esta modal teria que atualizar sem dar refresh na página inteira, somente nela para pegar o valor da `$_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido']` atual. Alguém sabe como fazer?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="altera_cliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header modal_pedido">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fechar"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">PedidoOnline gerado com sucesso!</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <a class='btn-info btn-mini' href='pedidos_pdf/pedido_/<?php echo $_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido']; ?>.pdf' target='_blank' download='Pedido_<?php echo $_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido']; ?>'><img border='0' src='./images/download9.png' alt='W3Schools'></a>
               </div>
               <p />
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sair</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Código javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.informacoes').click(function () {
      var dados = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: './ajax/pdf_pedido_faturado.php',
         data: 'pedido=' + dados,
         beforeSend: function () {
            $('<div class="ajaxModal"><div class="ajaxModal-preload"><p>Salvando PDF aguarde!</p></div></div>').insertAfter('body');
            $('.ajaxModal').fadeIn('fast');
         },
         success: function () {
            ajaxModal_Close();
            $('#altera_cliente').modal('show');
         }
      });
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: O que pdf_pedido_faturado.php retorna (HTML, Json, string)?

Comment: Neste arquivo eu faço select e salvo um arquivo PDF em uma pasta do meu site, ai gravo uma $_SESSION['numero_'] , eu não estou retornando nada somente esta session.

Comment: Quer atualizar a div com qual conteúdo?

Comment: Quero atualizar a div com o valor que esta na $_SESSION

Comment: <a class='btn-info btn-mini' href='pedidos_pdf/pedido_/<?php echo $_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido']; ?>.pdf' target='_blank' download='Pedido_<?php echo $_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido']; ?>'><img border='0' src='./images/download9.png' alt='W3Schools'></a>

Answer (score 0):

O PHP é gerado uma única vez do lado o servidor e então transferido com todas as informações necessárias ao browser e renderiza a página.

O que voce pode fazer é construiu um arquivo .php que dá um echo dessa variável de sessão e utilizando jquery voce chama e popula sua div.

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION['IMPR_PEDIDO']['pedido'];
?>
```

No jquery voce pode fazer assim

```
/* evento que abre é disparado quando o modal 
do bootstrap é aberto (supondo que voce está usando bootstrap*/

$('#meuModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    var callString = "url.php";
    $.get(callString, function (result) {
        $("#minhaDiv").text(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: cara desculpe minha ignorância mas não entendi, estou fazendo da seguinte maneiro. Tenho o arquivo busca_fotos.php ai nele tenho um require 'busca_fotos_mostra.php'; quando clico no bota de fotos da minha lista ele dispara um ajax que manda os dados via POST para um outro arquivo PHP esse busca o nome do arquivo da foto e salva na session, segue abaixo meu ajax.

Comment: Acho que seu comentario não coube inteiro, Maicon...

Comment: Essa e a parte que abre a modal so da erro na modal, lembrando que a modal é outro arquivo.
success: function (data) {
 if (data === 'FOTOS_OK') {
                                ajaxModal_Close();
                                $('#fotos').load('consulta_produto_fotos.php');
                                $('#fotos_prod').modal('show');
                            } else if (data === 'NAO_FOTOS') {
                                //alert(produto);
                                ajaxModal_Close();
                                $("#fotos_nao").modal();
 } }

Comment: O que voce precisa é mostra o nome da foto que está na sessão no titulo do modal '#fotos_prod', isso?

Comment: Na verdade na minha modal tenho um carrousel la faco foreach para exibir na tela as informacoes que foram salvas na session so que da erro

foreach ($_SESSION['fotos'] as $key => $value):
exibo as informacoes

Notice: Undefined index: fotos in C:\wamp\www\incoterm\consulta_produto_fotos.php on line 33

Comment: Voce está guardando um array dentro dessa variável?

Comment: Sera que poderia dar um help por skype depois posto a solucao aqui.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42554/discussion-between-andre-santarosa-and-maicon-fernando-stefene-da-sil).